# Why can some games run on my computer, but some others don't? Is it my video card?

Tags: pc, technical-issues

Maybe it is something else other than video card which makes some games run on my system when others don't.

I can play [NFS Most Wanted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Need_For_Speed:_Most_Wanted), released November 11th, 2005. However, I can't run [Metal gear solid 2 substance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_Gear_Solid_2:_Substance), [Prince of Persia: The Sands of Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_of_Persia:_Sands_of_Time) or [Splinter Cell: Chaos Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splinter_Cell:_Chaos_Theory), which actually are older and have lower requirements!

My system specs:

- Processor: P4 2.80 Ghz
- Ram: 512 mb
- chipset: intel 845g
- graphic controller: built-in intel 82845G
- OS : Win XP

How can i verify which game will be playable and which game will not be playable on my system?

Comment: I have trimmed down the question. The original version, enumerating system requirements for each of the four games is [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/bdcf64e3-4fda-4abd-87a7-6b85161ab37c/view-source).

Comment: Rakesh, what OS are you running on?

Comment: @badp: OS name mentioned. BTW, why have u trimmed the question? Is there any virtual character count limitation? :)

Comment: 512 mb of RAM? How are you still breathing? What browser are you using, Lynx?

Comment: @Ayelis You revived 6 years old question :)  .   Now, I don't have PC I have a laptop. 8gigs RAM, 2gigs GC, core i7 quad core.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no easy rule, the graphics card naming is made deliberately confusing, if you don't pay close attention to that area you have no chance of knowing how powerful a graphics card is. The amount of graphics RAM can be used for a very rough estimate of graphics performance, but that is not very reliable.

Your best bet is to try a demo version, if available. The next best thing is to search the official forums for the game for people trying to play the game with the same graphics card as you have.

You can also try [Can you Run it?](http://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri/), an online tool that checks your system requirements against various games. This tool requires access to your computer, it could theoretically do malicious actions on it. You'll have to trust it to be harmless.

Your graphics card is an old integrated graphics chip, you'll have problems playing anything even barely recent with that one.

Comment: i like the idea of playing demo. Also, i tested `Can you run it` it says i can't play NFS Most wanted but i can.

Comment: `Can you run` it makes sometimes errors, trying demos is the most reliable way I know of.

Comment: The trouble with figuring out whether a game will actually run on my computer is the primary reason I switched to console gaming :)

Answer (score 2):

What rami said ^^

http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/cs-014257.htm

The above matrix from intel indicates that your graphics chipset (82845G) does not support pixel shaders and vertex shaders.

If a game is programmed to use pixel shaders, then you will have problems. Some games are set up to downgrade. Many are not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to buy a graphics card that supports pixel shader version 1.4 or 2 to play Metal Gear Solid 2.